# Matching values in 2 columns of data frame and extracting specific values

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame composed of two groups of values each with 3 attributes (a1, a2, a3 and b1, b2, b3). I'd like to compare each value of column a1 with each value of column b1 to find a possible match. If there is a match, there's only one match.  Note that the two groups of values, a and b, have a different number of observations so a1, a2, a3 will have more rows than b1, b2, and b3.

```
   a1      a2     a3     b1    b2    b3
 ACTTG     10    0.345  AGGTC   2   0.198
 AGTTC      2    0.244  GGTAA   1   0.022
 AGGTC      4    0.211  CGTTA   1   0.022
 CGTTA      1    0.111 
 GCTAT      1    0.111
```

I need to find the a1 and b1 values that match and combine the a2,a3, b2,b3 in the new data frame like the table below.  In short, I'm trying to remove duplicates values between columns a1 and b1.  The values that match may or not be on the same rows.

```
   a1        a2      a3     b2     b3
  AGGTC       4     0.211   2    0.198
  CGTTA       1     0.111   1    0.022
```

I'm thinking of using match() but I can't get my head around it. I'm not familiar enough with r. I'd appreciate any suggestions.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use inner join

```
df1 <- data.table::fread("a1      a2     a3   
                          ACTTG     10    0.345  
                          AGTTC      2    0.244  
                          AGGTC      4    0.211 
                          CGTTA      1    0.111 
                          GCTAT      1    0.111")
             
df2 <- data.table::fread("b1    b2    b3
                         AGGTC   2   0.198
                         GGTAA   1   0.022
                         CGTTA   1   0.022")

# Keep only rows that both df have in common
df1 %>% 
dplyr::inner_join(df2, 
                  by= c("a1" = "b1")) #need to specify column do join on

#      a1 a2    a3 b2    b3
# 1: AGGTC  4 0.211  2 0.198
# 2: CGTTA  1 0.111  1 0.022


# Keep all rows of `left' df
df1 %>% dplyr::left_join(df2, by= c("a1" = "b1"))

# a1 a2    a3 b2    b3
# 1: ACTTG 10 0.345 NA    NA
# 2: AGTTC  2 0.244 NA    NA
# 3: AGGTC  4 0.211  2 0.198
# 4: CGTTA  1 0.111  1 0.022
# 5: GCTAT  1 0.111 NA    NA
```

Comment: Very cool. So simple.  It works well.  One additional question.  How do I get the script to also print the a1 and b1 rows that are not shared?

Comment: @Orion11 do you mean a left join? I added it to the answer

Comment: exactly! Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You probably could get something messy worked out with match, but I'd suggest using merge() instead.

```
df1<-data.frame(c("A","B","C"),c(1,2,3))
df2<-data.frame(c("B","A","d"),c(5,7,9))
names(df1)<-c("id","a1")
names(df2)<-c("id","b1")

merge(df1,df2,by="id")

  id a1 b1
1  A  1  7
2  B  2  5
```

Comment: This solution is a good one too. It does require the extra step of renaming the “a1” and “b1” columns. On the other hand it doesn’t require the use of any library except for the Base.

Comment: By using the “ALL” option of merge I can introduce the non-matching rows. Thanks